# Как растянуть background HTML5, CSS3

Tags: html5, css3

Посмотрите ниже на мою проблему, фон не на весь экран, css3 код прикрепил снизу!

```css
body {
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
 background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat fixed;;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; 
       background-size: cover;
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```